# Python running clock in separate window

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought I would make a running clock program. I have this code which works for what I want it to do, but I want it to be fancy and output it to a new window. I thought of a message box but that would need constant closing.

Is there way around this, or should I just stick to using the console?

```
x=0
import datetime
import time
while x<10:
    currentTime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(str(currentTime))
```

**EDIT:**
This is what i have now but the window goes all over the place.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import * 
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *  

import datetime
import time

x=0
while x<10:
    root = Tk()
    prompt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt))
    label1.pack()

    def close_after_1s():
        root.destroy()

    root.after(1000, close_after_1s)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you wanna open a new window, you wanna learn about Tkinter or QT or a similar GUI toolkit

Comment: i have used tkinter to create a message box which self destructs after 1 second but this used too much cpu for the clock

Comment: how about creating a window with some label and updating the label with the current time?

Comment: check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the point of Tk. The entire thing is a loop(hence the mainloop) and you keep destroying and creating a new window, hence the all over the place.

I think you just want something to update every sec:

```
from Tkinter import Tk,StringVar,Label
import datetime

def update():
    global prompt,root
    prompt.set(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    root.after(1000, update)

root = Tk()
prompt = StringVar()
label1 = Label(root, textvar=prompt, width=len(prompt.get()))
label1.pack()
update()
root.mainloop()
```

and my suggestion is to put all of this in a class. Google some Tk examples.